# ZeroMQ get client connection info

Tags: c++, c, zeromq

Ok so I have  the following case:

I am using ZeroMQ to pass around messages to other nodes in a cluster. I would like to have a master cluster that keeps track of who is in the cluster and tells other nodes when a node connects to the cluster. So for instance:

1. New node wants to join cluster.
2. New node announces to master server intent to join
3. Master server tells other existing nodes about new node
4. Other existing nodes connect to the new node.

From what I can tell I cant get information on the address of the new node when it tries to connect to a socket on the master server so I was wondering if there was any sort of way that I could try to forward on information about the new node to the other nodes.

Edit: I just noticed functionality that seems like it might be what I want in the monitoring abilities. Is this the only way to do so? And will it even be what I really want.

Comment: Why not use JOIN method which notifies every node that a new one has joined?

Comment: what JOIN method do you speak of?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using [Group Messaging](http://books.google.pl/books?id=KWtT5CJc6FYC&pg=PA117&dq=ZeroMQ+new+node+wants+to+join+a+cluster&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qPVMUorjJ6qE4ASHuYH4CQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=join&f=false) pattern instead. In this pattern instead of talkng to a single master node, you tell to a group of nodes.

There are [JOIN](http://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:20) and [LEAVE](http://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:20) commands. When a node joins a group it broadcast a JOIN command to all its peers, thus telling them he has joined.